# In a right-angled triangle, given Vector2D of pointA, pointB and an angle, what's the Vector2D of pointC?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please see my attached picture, it's a 2D game, I have the Vectors of PointA and PointB, and the degree of the AngleA, and the angle-C is a right angle.
I'm wondering how can I get the Vector of PointC?

It would be nice if there are existing APIs in Unity that could solve this, otherwise, higher performance of culculation would be cool.

Thank you very much for checking this out.

[image: attached picture]

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-triangles.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your promp reply, but I still don't get it, even I can get the length of all line segments, but how I can get the X, Y coordinates of VectorC? Can I have more clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [given Link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-triangles.html) what you can get is all line lengths and according angles since you already know two of them.

I hope I don't get it wrong but I'll try best. There also might be more elegant solutions, though.

So you know `A`, `B` and `angleA` and thereby also the vector `ab` (A -> B) and its length ( = distance between A and B). You also know that `angleC = 90` so it follows automatically that `angleB = 180 - 90 - angleA`.

Assuming for now we are speaking 2D space XY as you draw it.

```c#
// Given values
Vector2 A;
Vector2 B;
float angleA; // in degrees

var ab = B - A;
// The same but with length = 1 (will need this later)
var abNorm = ab.normalized;
var lengthAB = Vector2.Distance(A, B);
```

Now we want to add a second vector A->C which you get from the angleB (= 180 - 90 - angleA) and the length of b (= (ab * sin(angleB))/sin(90)).

```c#
var angleB = 90 - angleA;
var lengthAC = lengthAB * Mathf.Sin(angleB * Mathf.Deg2Rad) / Mathf.Sin(90 * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
```

Now the tricky part: we have the vector `abNorm` as direction with length `1` so we can take this vector and rotate it about `angleB` degrees.

```c#
var acNorm = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * angleA) * abNorm;
// give it the correct length
var ac = acNorm * lengthAC;
```

Finally you would only have to make this vector start from `B` which should return the position of `C`:

```c#
var C = B + bc;
```

---

*Please note: Typed on smartphone real quick and not sure if there is any more elegant or built-in solution but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Although I didn't get exactly the expected output with this, but this greatly inspired me, thanks a lot for the answer, especially the codes!